# Ion-gallery not opening image in fullscreen

Tags: angularjs, plugins, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic plugin "ion-gallery" `https://github.com/pedroabreu/ion-gallery` and following the instructions on the github page, but I can not get the images to open in full screen. I am running it through `ionic serve` or is it something that it needs to be running on a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing through bower

```
bower install ion-gallery
```

it installs a older version. So for the latest features download the newest version [here](https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-gallery)